# How can I get the angle on radian on wolfram?

Tags: geometry, wolfram-alpha

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sqrt(6)%2Bi*sqrt(2))%2F(2-2i)), the argument of a complex number in degrees is given. How can I ask wolfram to convert it into radians (they give an approximation).

Comment: Try the following: [$\displaystyle \arg \left( \frac{\sqrt{6}+i\sqrt{2}}{2-2i} \right)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg((sqrt(6)%2Bi*sqrt(2))%2F(2-2i)))

Comment: @Math Beginner Check out degree to radian conversion taking input of argument of complex number.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ degrees is $x \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$ radians. This follows because the angle in a semi-circle is $180^{\circ}$ and $\pi$ radians. So the relation $180^{\circ} \mapsto \pi$ radians gives $x^{\circ} \mapsto \frac{\pi x}{180}$ radians.

Edit to answer edited question: [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=argument+of+%5B(sqrt(6)%2Bi*sqrt(2))%2F(2-2i)%5D+in+radians) will make Wolfram convert the argument to radians.

Comment: @MathBeginner I've edited the answer to answer your clarified question.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: @MathBeginner Fixed

Comment: You of course gave me an answer that work (that's why I upvoted). But it doesn't really answer to my question. I would like to have all the information that I get in my link with not using degree. In fact, I don't understand why they use degree... neither why this unit still exist...